# how to use in_array in ejs template

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

How to use in_array or similar in inside an ejs template?

This is how I use it on php:

```
<?php
$cur_repository_id = array();
foreach($dbrepos as $row){
    $shared_ids = $row['shared_ids'];
    if(in_array($user_id, $shared_ids)){
        $selected = "selected";
        $cur_repository_id[] = $row['rep_id'];
    }else{
        $selected = "";
    }
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['rep_id'];?>" <?php echo $selected;?>><?php echo $row['namespace'];?></option>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, you have to show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equivalent of `in_array` in javascript is [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

So if for example you want to pass an array from `Node.js` to `ejs` file, you can do something like that:

```
res.render('index', {numbers : [1, 23, 44]});
```

And then inside `ejs` you can use the method `includes`, for example:

```
<body>
    <% if(numbers.includes(44)){ %>
        <h1>44 exists</h1>
    <% } else{ %>
        <h1>44 not exists</h1>
    <% } %>
</body>
```

Also you can use method [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), which return the index of given value in an array.